# Java Hibernate Why executeUpdate on namedQuery executes full table update first?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, named-query

I have a simple NamedQuery like this

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery(name="namedQuery",query="update entity set .... where id=:id"
```

I have a method like this

```
public void updateField(final Entity entity){
    final Session session = currentSession();
    final org.hibernate.Query query= session.getNamedQuery("namedQuery")
            ...loadParameters();
    query.executeUpdate();
    return;     
}
```

This always works alright but sometimes in this line of code

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

Sometimes I see in the console a select from the entity like ***a full update of the entity***. I don't understand why this happens; if I really want to update a simple field why Hibernate updates me all the fields? When this happens the only single update of the namedQuery seems useless because was I think was updated before.

Something like this i see this in the console

```
Hibernate: 
/* update
    com.models.Entity */ update
        entity 
    set
        BUNCH OF FIELDS
    where
        ID=?
```

and later I see what I really want the only field being updated

```
update
    Entity
set
    SINGLE_FIELD_UPDATE  
where
    ID=?
```

As I mentioned, the full update sometimes appears sometimes **do not** and sometimes the full update appears **twice** before the update of the `namedQuery` being executed!

Why is this? Why does Hibernate fire a full update and something twice the full update before the real field in the `namedQuery` being executed?

I am missing something?

Comment: have you tried annotating your class with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
  dynamicUpdate = true
)`?

Comment: it works.. post your comment to mark it a solved

Comment: posted my answer with the official link of the documentation. glad i helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please annotate your class with

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity( dynamicUpdate = true )
```

see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html)

Comment: I still dont understand why Hibernate fires a update before namedQuery being executed???

Comment: do you reference it at another entity with cascadeType.ALL or sth similar?

Comment: It has 3  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    @JoinColumn(name = "C02") alike